# Find the polynomial $p∈P(\Bbb F)$ of lowest possible degree using Lagrange interpolation

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification

Let $\Bbb F=\Bbb Z_{11}$. Using Lagrange interpolation, find the polynomial $p∈P(\Bbb F)$ of lowest possible degree such that

$p([1])=[1],  p([0])=[2],  p([3])=[0].$

here is my work, I'm not sure if my calculation is right,I'm little confuse with mod calculate

[image: mod11]

Comment: Have you checked your answer, to see whether it gives the right values at $[1]$, $[0]$, and $[3]$?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Yes,i think im doing right

Comment: The mistake is in the first line. $[0][3]\neq [3]$